Python жалуется на переменную, которая якобы не привязана к значению
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import random

import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = 
telebot.TeleBot('токен не спалю')

code_security = 9223
data = [["", "", "", ""]]
data_user = []

# где-то 60 строчек

print("Бот в работе,  если хотите собрать данные о 
пациентах,зайдите в бота и введите /data")
    def check_and_continue_2(message):
    if message.text == "/start":
        print("Стоп машина, форма сбросилась")
    else:
        data_user.append(message.text)
        msg1 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg1, check_and_continue_3)

def check_and_continue_3(message):

    if message.text == "/start":
        print("Стоп машина, форма сбросилась")
    else:
        data_user.append(message.text)
        msg1 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg1, check_and_continue_4)
    
def check_and_continue_4(message):
    if message.text == "/start":
        print("Стоп машина, форма сбросилась")
    else:
        data_user.append(message.text)
        msg1 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg1, check_and_continue_5)

def check_and_continue_5(message):

    **data_user.append(message.text)**
    data.append(data_user)
    data_user = []

Возникла проблема с переменной data_user (UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'data_user' where it is not associated with a value), которая была создана как пустой список. Я вставил код, где она (переменная) изменялась. Строчка с проблемой выделена. Помогите, горит заказ

«которая была создана как пустой список» — в будущем, двумя строчками ниже. К сожалению, питон не умеет путешествовать во времени

нет, дорогой, переменную я еще выше определил

мне надо было просто переменную очистить

А это не имеет никакого значения, если вы пытаетесь создать локальную переменную в будущем двумя строчками ниже

Очистка переменной и создание переменной — таки разные вещи

говорю же Я СОЗДАЛ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ ВЫШЕ, ПРОСТО НЕ ОХВАТИЛ ЭТОТ КУСОК КОДА!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! извиняюсь за то что я сорвался

А это НЕ ИМЕЕТ НИКАКОГО ЗНАЧЕНИЯ, если вы пытаетесь СОЗДАТЬ ЛОКАЛЬНУЮ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ в будущем двумя строчками ниже

да не пытаюсь я ее создать, я сейчас просто весь код выложу на гитхаб там и посмотришь

Тем не менее сейчас показанный вами код содержит строчку, которая создаёт локальную переменную data_user = []

щас выложу гитхаб посмотришь

А какой в этом смысл, если вы выложите туда точно такое же создание локальной переменной

Ну и в любом случае — просто вбиваем UnboundLocalError в поиск и получаем кучу аналогичных вопросов-дубликатов на любой вкус с ответами, среди которых обязательно найдётся и решение вашей проблемы

В частности, вот такой эталонный вопрос — Почему из функции недоступна глобальная переменная?

бро, т. к. я гит щас не смогу залить я весь код сюда запихну

Вам правильную ссылку дали. Питон не видит внешних переменных в функциях

@SwaD видит, но только если не пытаться создавать локальные переменные с таким же названием (поэтому функции 2-3-4 работают, а функция 5 нет)

@andreymal а, менять не может(явно перезаписывать), а append это не изменение переменной.

Вы пытаетесь использовать переменную data_user в функции check_and_continue_5, когда она объявлена в теле этой же функции. Язык требует, чтобы переменная была объявлена перед её использованием. Можете сделать переменную data_user глобальной внутри функции или передавать её как параметр в функции, где она используется.
Вариант 1:
def check_and_continue_5(message):
    global data_user
    data_user.append(message.text)
    data.append(data_user)
    data_user = []

Вариант 2:
def check_and_continue_5(message, data_user):
    data_user.append(message.text)
    data.append(data_user)
    data_user = []

При этом во всех вызовах check_and_continue_5 вам нужно будет передавать data_user как аргумент.
Еще можно реализовать объект класса или словарь для хранения данных вместо использования глобальных переменных:
class UserData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_user = []

def check_and_continue_2(message, user_data):
    if message.text == "/start":
        print("Стоп машина, форма сбросилась")
    else:
        user_data.data_user.append(message.text)
        msg1 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg1, check_and_continue_3, user_data)

def check_and_continue_3(message, user_data):
    if message.text == "/start":
        print("Стоп машина, форма сбросилась")
    else:
        user_data.data_user.append(message.text)
        msg1 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg1, check_and_continue_4, user_data)

def check_and_continue_4(message, user_data):
    if message.text == "/start":
        print("Стоп машина, форма сбросилась")
    else:
        user_data.data_user.append(message.text)
        msg1 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg1, check_and_continue_5, user_data)

def check_and_continue_5(message, user_data):
    user_data.data_user.append(message.text)
    data.append(user_data.data_user)
    user_data.data_user = []

# Использование:
user_data = UserData()
check_and_continue_2(message, user_data)


господи я ведь создал переменную

создал раньше чем 2 функция

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы пытаетесь изменить значение глобальной переменной внутри функции без использования global.

def check_and_continue_5(message):
    global data_user
    data_user.append(message.text)
    data.append(data_user)
    data_user = []


то есть мне перед изменением переменной user_data её заглобалить?

Ага. Вариант 1 попробуйте

Если вы хотите изменить значение глобальной переменной внутри функции, вам нужно будет явно указать, что переменная является глобальной с помощью ключевого слова global. Это и вызывает затруднение

@GxdTxnz Если ваш комментарий адресован кому то конкретно, то используйте @ для обращения. Тогда данному участнику придет уведомление
